# gcp python function - delete kubernetes namespaces, and get .kube/config file

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, bucket

I want to create a python script in google functions - that deletes given namespace, 
But there is 2 problems with that - the function can't access to the global `kubeconfig` file - I got errors that there is no configuration file
so:
 I have created config file, uploaded it to bucket and trying to use it from the bucket in `KubeConfig()` 
this way:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("kyc-tfstate-staging")
blob=bucket.get_blob("storage/config2")
conf = KubeConfig(blob)
print(conf)
```

I got the next output:

```
kubeconfig.kubeconfig.KubeConfig object at 0x7feee1868a58
```

after that i try to print all the namespaces that i have:

```
v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
response = v1.list_namespace()
print(response)
```

and I got the next error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/namespaces (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe49e098a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a known issue but as it can see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47520#issuecomment-320733993), in the version 3.0 must be fixed. In addition, as a workaround, you use the following:

```
    os.environ['KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST'] = 'kubernetes'
    config.load_incluster_config()
```